# Laravel Homestead - no config.json file

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am currently trying to install Laravel/Homestead with Vagrant. I am running into an issue when I try to run homestead up. I get an error that says "There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/tyler-holhubner/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile
Message: No such file or directory - var/config.json"

I have been following a video on Laracasts about installing homestead, but nothing I have tried is working.

Answer (score 0):

I simply performed the vagrant init wrong. I went to the directory which contained the homestead files and executed vagrant init, I should have done vagrant init laravel/homestead. Everything is working as it should now.